# Applications disappear after unlocking (16.10)

Tags: unity, 16.04, lock-screen, bug-reporting, 16.10

Chrome and Slack clients show as open in the task bar, but their windows are nowhere to be found.  Clicking icons in task bar does no good - must terminate applications and restart them.  Problem first appeared in 16.04, but continues after upgrade to 16.10 on an HP Probook with an HDMI monitor (so, two screens active).

Seeing many similar experiences, and no feedback.